# Getting the difference between two repositories

Tags: git, git-diff

How can we get the difference between two git repositories?

The scenario:
We have a repo_a and repo_b. The latter was created as a copy of repo_a. There have been parallel development in both the repositories afterwards. Is there a way we can list the differences of the current versions of these two repositories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare two git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687450/how-do-i-compare-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 354, accepted):

In repo_a:

```
git remote add -f b path/to/repo_b.git
git remote update
git diff master remotes/b/master
git remote rm b
```

Comment: I had to specify remotes/b/master as per the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4710379/284051

Comment: What if you need to compare repo_a/master with a specific tag of repo_b?

Comment: not working for me, it's throwing: fatal: ambiguous argument 'remotes/b/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'      Any ideas here?

Comment: I'm getting the same as @AndrewHeekin. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Actually I fixed it. Seems my check-in of the other remote failed so there was no code in the repo. After I added the code I had to re-add the remote (I'm sure I couldn't updated it without re-adding but I didnt know how) but it works now. thanks!

Comment: @parliament @AndrewHeekin: See my revision to the answer. You need to run `git remote update` before `diff`ing.

Comment: I seem to need to specify `origin/master` rather than a bare `master`. Also, this finds the difference between the master branches, so what if you want to find all branches that are different? E.g. to check the status of a repository backup?

Comment: Can you explain what is doing every line? Thanks !

Comment: Just wondering, but `-f` (`git fetch b` after setting up the remote information) is doing less than `git remote update` (`git fetch` for each remote) - is there an additional reason for it being there?

Comment: @DavidTorres, were you able to get your answer?

Comment: @NasifImtiazOhi I don't recall... this was more than 6 years ago 

Comment: This is not working for me. Using `/path/to/local/directory` instead of `/path/to/repo_b.git` works initially but then after `git remote update` the `git diff` returns Andrew's "ambiguous argument" error. Using `githubusername/repo.git` gives `fatal: does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: Ah, figured it out! First line needs the full `https://` for the remote path: `git remote add -f b https://github.com/username/repo_b.git`

Comment: Tried to edit but the suggested edit queue is full.

Comment: simple and helpful, it works

Comment: I am surprised that this is considered a correct answer. Doesn't it compare only the master branch in the two repos?  Doesn't it ignore other branches and tags?  Ditto ~/.git/config contents and remote names?

Answer (score 74):

[Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) can compare directories:

```
meld directory1 directory2
```

Just use the directories of the two git repos and you will get a nice graphical comparison:

[image]

When you click on one of the blue items, you can see what changed.

Comment: Meld freezes while compare projects in my VS solution, BeyondCompare is not.

Comment: in OSX: diff -rq folder1 folder2

Comment: Wonderful link! Very simple program, I am now using this as my diff program for OSX.

Comment: This is absolutely lovely!
Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm not sure if meld is capable of handling files that are ignored by git - you should consider this while using it

Comment: WinMerge can do this too

Comment: That was the solution for me. Very easy git repository comparisson.

Comment: best comparision program ever, very very useful to compare projects ...

Comment: Adding exclusion to diff was winner for me on macOS  `diff -rq folder1 folder2  --exclude=".git" --exclude=".DS_Store"`

Answer (score 19):

You can add other repo first as a remote to your current repo:

```
git remote add other_name PATH_TO_OTHER_REPO
```

then fetch brach from that remote:

```
git fetch other_name branch_name:branch_name
```

this creates that branch as a new branch in your current repo, then you can diff that branch with any of your branches, for example, to compare current branch against new branch(branch_name):

```
git diff branch_name
```

Comment: `branch_name:branch_name` where `other_name_branch:new_local_repo_branch_name`

Answer (score 11):

I use PyCharm which has great capabilities to compare between folders and files.

Just open the parent folder for both repos and wait until it indexes. Then you can use right click on a folder or file and `Compare to...` and pick the corresponding folder / file on the other side.

It shows not only what files are different but also their content. 
Much easier than command line.

Answer (score 10):

An easy way to do that without touching your remotes config.
From repo A, in master (assume you want to compare master branches):

```
git fetch path/to/repo_b.git master
git diff FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 9):

Once you have both branches in one repository you can do a `git diff`. And getting them in one repository is as easy as

```
git fetch /the/other/repo/.git refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/other/*
```

Comment: Is there a way to cherry-pick history with a little change: For example in remote repo file is placed in one directory, but I want apply changes to same file but which is placed in different directory in local repo?

Comment: If you're talking about a small change, I think the easiest would be just to make a diff and then reapply it to the other file using patch.

Comment: Patch is not applied because of different file names despite on those are same files

Comment: Oh, I was only thinking of different directories, not file names (directories can be easily handled via patch options). Well, for the filenames I'd just change them manually or through the script. That said, I'm not saying there's no better solution, just what I can come up with without digging anywhere.

Comment: what if I want to compare all branches, though?

Answer (score 9):

```
git diff master remotes/b
```

That's incorrect. `remotes/b` is a remote, but not a branch.

To get it to work, I had to do:

```
git diff master remotes/b/master
```

Comment: This should really be a comment on the relevant answer.

Answer (score 8):

See [http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitTips](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips#How_to_compare_two_local_repositories), section "How to compare two local repositories" in "General".

In short you are using GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES environment variable to have access to object database of the other repository, and using [git rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) with `--git-dir` / GIT_DIR to convert symbolic name in other repository to SHA-1 identifier.

Modern version would look something like this (assuming that you are in 'repo_a'):

```
GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=../repo_b/.git/objects \
   git diff $(git --git-dir=../repo_b/.git rev-parse --verify HEAD) HEAD
```

where `../repo_b/.git` is path to object database in repo_b (it would be repo_b.git if it were bare repository).  Of course you can compare arbitrary versions, not only HEADs.

---

Note that if repo_a and repo_b are the same repository, it might make more sense to put both of them in the same repository, either using "`git remote add -f ...`" to create nickname(s) for repository for repeated updates, or obe off "`git fetch ...`"; as described in other responses.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command:

```
diff -x .git -r repo-A repo-B
```

or for the side by side you can use:

```
diff -x .git -W200 -y -r repo-A repo-B
```

In case of Colorizing every diff file, you can use:

```
diff -x .git -W200 -y -r repo-A repo-B | sed -e "s/\(^diff .*\)/\x1b[31m\1\x1b[0m/"
```

Comment: based on @andrew-heekin solution

Answer (score 2):

To follow up @iamamac answer to have a nice **summary** after this:

```
git remote add -f b path/to/repo_b.git
git remote update
```

I would use **diff-tree**:

```
git diff-tree master remotes/b/master --compact-summary
```

Comment: Can this path be on a remote computer as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have both repos on your local machine and use the linux diff command with the two directories as parameters:

`diff -r repo-A repo-B`

Comment: The only way to make this usable is to rename one of the .git directories. this reduces to two lines pages of differences that don't matter. Been there, done that, came here looking for a better answer.

Comment: AFAICT this *almost* compares everything in two repos - objects, config stuff, most refs and remotes.  But if git-pack-refs has packed different sets of refs in the two repos, the diff -r may say different, even though logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Reminder to self... fetch first, else the repository has not local hash (I guess).

step 1. Setup the upstream remote and above^

diffing a single file follows this pattern :

git diff localBranch uptreamBranch --spacepath/singlefile

`git diff master upstream/nameofrepo -- src/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use WinMerge for this if you have both the repositories in your machine- https://winmerge.org/?lang=en
2. It has a good user interface and very easy to see, merge the
   difference or any task you like for the files or folders
3. Open WinMerge and then  select file -> Open command
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhKxv.png
4. Select the two or more repositories which that is located in your machine
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoA2V.png
5. Then you will be able to see the changes in the file if there are any(They will be marked as red).
6. You can compare the difference between repositories by just double clicking the the required file.
7. It has so many cool features and I really recommend this to you all.