# Setting up git for branches from already existing environments (no shared history in git)

Tags: git, git-branch

I have code in 2 environments, UAT and PROD.  Say I make a copy of the UAT code and put it on the UAT branch, and likewise for PROD.  When doing a PR from UAT to PROD, I'd want to see the differences between the two (they are mostly the same, but there are a few things in UAT that are not in PROD yet).  But git says there's nothing to compare because they're different histories.  Which is true.

Is there a way to remedy this so I can see the differences and start promoting code from UAT to PROD via git?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968512/getting-the-difference-between-two-repositories) relate/help with your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PROD` code should be in the `main` branch. Then create and checkout a new branch from `main`, let's say `import/UAT`.

On the `import/UAT` branch, do a file diff , not a `git diff` against the code in your existing `UAT` branch. You may need to copy those files to another location to do the file comparison. I'd use something like [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/). You can copy/commit those changes into `import/UAT`.

Now you'll have your git history between the two environments.

While on `import/UAT` you can do a `git diff main --name-only` to see a list of file names that have changed and work from there.

**Update:**

If you do a file compare with a good tool, you can bulk copy all changes from the source `UAT` folder to the folder containing your repo on `import/UAT`. Then you can bulk add all changes in one command.

```
git add .
git commit -m "UAT changes."
```

You can even try just copying the existing UAT files into the repo folder while you have `import/UAT` checked out. `git` will most likely figure out file deltas and additions regardless of the file's timestamp.

Comment: I get what you're doing here with the branching.  But does this require manually applying the content from uat to import/uat, for each changed file one by one?  Or maybe just as tedious, finding the last commit for each file on uat and applying it to import/uat?  Other ideas?

Comment: Manually can be one at a time or in bulk. Updated.